XOR gate (74xx86) not XOR'ing with DRAM (4164) on breadboard
I have been trying to use a series of XOR gates (74LS86, 74HC86, even CD4070) to invert address lines going to a 4164 DRAM, but am having little luck. Here's a drawing to illustrate my setup on the breadboard:

The XOR gates are placed in-between the interface (microprocessor, etc.) and the DRAM, with one input of each XOR gate tied to a common line that is either pulled low (0V) or high (5V).
The issue I am having is that when I pull the common lines high the data is not inverted. Well, in the past few months I've managed a couple of times to get it to "work", but the signal has been rather noisy.
I have tried using a SPDT toggle, a SPDT from a CD4053 (also tried 74HC4053, CD74HCT4053, etc.) and even directly connecting the common lines to 5V, and still no inversion. For the common line I have also tried pull-up resistors, pull-down resistors, low pass filtering A7 and using that as an XOR clock control signal, inverters (74xx), Schmitt triggers, flip flops (74xx), 555 trigger/threshold trick, you name it.
What am I missing? How to get this to work even somewhat reliably on breadboard before I move to PCB?

Breadboards and high-speed digital signals don't mix well. How long are the wires and are you using bypass capacitors?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Often true. Bypass capacitors always (100nF per IC), and the wires are 2-3 inches (those little multi-pack connector wires).

What (roughly) frequency are we talking here?

Between 500kHz-2MHz, so nothing crazy (I actually have other oscillators in a slightly higher range of 1-7MHz working just fine on breadboard even as simple Schmitt trigger oscillators). As I had mentioned, it seems to sometimes work, but the signal is very noisy (lots of artifacts), and more often than not it doesn't work, so I'm trying to foolproof it so that I know it will be reliable when I move on to PCB.

Without parapsychology it's pretty hard to guess where the issues are coming from.

The principle is sound though, am I correct? I've seen this used in other applications, and I just want to make sure that I'm not misunderstanding the core ideas.

You're introducing a propagation delay, but other than that it should work if the timing limits (like address setup and hold times) are still okay in the modified design. Mucking with clock lines like nRAS/nCAS is a lot more prone to issues.

Is this still the same problem you were asking about back in July?

@paraparabolic I will only use wireless breadboards for audio. Sure, I might consider them for a little higher. But not anywhere near 1 MHz (or above.) Too many bad experiences trying. You might skim this Digikey article for a short note about low speed there. I would not begin to try helping diagnose this over the web. My crystal ball never worked and you are in the weeds. I understand you think you have evidence to the contrary. But that and 3" wires is a gray area I wouldn't touch. Wirewrap was hard enough.

Do you have any oscilloscope traces of the signals?

(A transient recorder rather. (Dang. Can't remember if the 4164 had auto refresh.) There will be an address multiplexer somewhere: One alternative to XORs would be inverters.)

@DaveTweed it's the same issue but a different approach - with that question I was trying to use up/down counters, but eventually went back to trying out XOR gates because it seemed like the more suitable solution.

@greybeard I thought about inverters, but I'd like to be able to invert/non-invert the data at will, and unfortunately I haven't been able to find a family of inverters that have a control pin for all of them.

(SN74H87 where hard to find 45 years ago. About the time frame of the venerable 4164: care to name the bigger picture all of this features in?)
